# How to use cmake pack redhat-style rpm, which is major and "-devel"?

Tags: c++, cmake, rpmbuild

I have tried to use cmake to pack redhat style rpms.
Classical RedHat-style rpms are consist of 2 rpm, one is `package-version.rpm` and another is `package-devel-version.rpm`. But I failed.

For example, the project `foo`, which contains

```
- bin/demo 
- lib/libfoo.so.1.2.3
- lib/libfoo.so.1 
- lib/libfoo.so
- include/foo.h
```

I want `foo-1.2.3.rpm` to contain `bin/demo`, `lib/libfoo.so.1`, `lib/libfoo.so.1.2.3` and `foo-devel-1.2.3.rpm` to contain `lib/libfoo.so`, `include/foo.h`.

But now, I can only get `foo-1.2.3-major.rpm` (`bin/demo`, `lib/libfoo.so`, `lib/libfoo.so.1`, `lib/libfoo.so.1.2.3`) and `foo-1.2.3-devel.rpm` (`include/foo.h`).

```
# CMakeLists.txt 

project (foo)

include (GNUInstallDirs)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH 3)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE 1)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "The CMake Demo Project")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR RPM)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL major devel)

include (CPackComponent)
include (CPack)
cpack_add_component(major DISPLAY_NAME Major)
cpack_add_component(devel DISPLAY_NAME Development)

add_executable (demo demo.cxx)

add_library (foo SHARED foo.cxx foo.h)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES VERSION 1.2.3 SOVERSION 1)

install (TARGETS demo foo
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    COMPONENT major
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT major
    )
install (FILES foo.h
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    COMPONENT devel
    )
```

Thanks to @Tsyvarev, I have made some progress.
Add line `set(CPACK_RPM_MAIN_COMPONENT major)` before `include(CPack)`, I get follwing result. The rpm name `foo-1.2.3.rpm` is correct now.

```
]$ rpm -ql --qf "%{name}-%{version}\n" -p foo-1.2.3-devel.rpm
foo-devel-1.2.3
/usr/include/foo.h

]$ rpm -ql --qf "%{name}-%{version}\n" -p foo-1.2.3.rpm
foo-1.2.3
/usr/bin/demo
/usr/lib64/libfoo.so
/usr/lib64/libfoo.so.1
/usr/lib64/libfoo.so.1.2.3
```

But the filename of `foo-1.2.3-devel.rpm` is still incorrect, and the files inside rpm are still wrong.

Comment: You probably are looking for `CPACK_RPM_MAIN_COMPONENT` variable, which can be assigned to the name of the component, for which no file suffix needs to be created. See [CPackRPM documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/CPackRPM.html) for more info.

Comment: This sounds right. At runtime, most applications will just look for libfoo.so, which is likely a symlink to foo.major and that is a link to foo.major.minor. The only thing different for developers is the header file. I've also seen the static versions in `-devel` or `-static` packages.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: no. libfoo.so is only needed for building, like the headers. libfoo.so.major is what you need at runtime. OP description is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I finished my CMakeLists.txt

```
# CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo" CACHE STRING "build type")

project (foo VERSION 1.2.3 HOMEPAGE_URL "http://null")

include (GNUInstallDirs)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "The CMake Demo Project")
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL major devel)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR RPM)
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE 10)
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE_DIST  ON)
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_RPM_MAIN_COMPONENT major) # Which set the major package name to foo instead of foo-major
set(CPACK_RPM_FILE_NAME "RPM-DEFAULT") # Which makes the rpm name from foo-1.2.3-devel to foo-devel-1.2.3
set(CPACK_RPM_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE ON)
set(CPACK_RPM_DEBUGINFO_SINGLE_PACKAGE ON)

# you must include it here after set(CPACK...) and befor cpack_add_... 
include (CPack) 

cpack_add_component(major DESCRIPTION "Something for demo")
cpack_add_component(devel DESCRIPTION "For Development")

add_executable (demo demo.cxx)

add_library (foo SHARED foo.cxx foo.h)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES VERSION 1.2.3 SOVERSION 1)

set(PUBLIC_HEADERS foo.h)

install (TARGETS demo foo
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    COMPONENT major
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT major
    NAMELINK_COMPONENT devel # Which separate libfoo.so into foo-devel rpm, but it requires cmake-3.12, RHEL-8 takes 3.11.
    )
install (FILES ${PUBLIC_HEADERS}
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
    COMPONENT devel
    )
install (FILES README.md
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
    COMPONENT devel
    )
```

A workaround for RHEL-8 with cmake-3.11:

```
# install libfoo.so.1.2.3 and libfoo.so.1
install (TARGETS foo
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT major
    NAMELINK_SKIP
    )
# install libfoo.so
install (TARGETS foo
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT devel
    NAMELINK_ONLY
    )
```

Thanks to all